# Showing total of amount in view

Tags: views

I am listing the fee of students in a view developed using views 3. How can I show the total of fee for all records displayed at bottom as Total Fee:

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [Views Calc](http://drupal.org/project/views_calc).

> This module adds simple calculations to a views table. Requires the
>   Views module.
>
> You can SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, MIN, MAX, or AVG selected columns. A plug
>   in theme makes the view look more spreadsheet-like (right justifies
>   numeric fields, shades calculated columns and rows, and underlines
>   calculated rows).

Comment: I have used this module it works fine for showing the total but ends up with errors. Some other functionality of my views stops working. Please suggest me something else.

Comment: You're probably better off opening another question and actually listing your errors.